# Join and 'collectively' manipulate a de-normalized one-to-many split conditionally after the fact

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

Tricky thing to title and explain accurately - let me know if anything's unclear.

I have a de-normalized dataflow, consider:

```
Input one:

ID
Value
FKID

Input two:
FKID
DiffValue
CheckValue
```

Input one can have more than one input two row, relating on FKID obviously.

Now, after the joining I might have something like:

```
[ID] - [Value] - [DiffValue] - [CheckValue]
1 - A - D1 - C1
1 - A - D2 - C1
1 - A - D3 - C2
```

I then go through a conditional split, based off the CheckValue - searching for value: C2. If C2, change Value to DiffValue. Leaving me with:

Split one:

```
1 - A - D1 - C1
1 - A - D2 - C1
```

Split two:

```
1 - D3 - D3 - C2
```

Now I'd like to make sure that all of my rows have that D3 value. The thing here is, that it's possible for the split never to become true, in which case I need it to just go on, keeping the original A value, but if just ONE of the rows fulfill the checkvalue condition, all of the rows need the DiffValue.

A script transformation component won't work, as it's based on buffer, and I can't cache all the rows, perform code on the entire collection of rows at once, before sending them to output. I can't even do a simple save ID to temp SQL and do a lookup based on ID afterwards, because after the conditional split it's two parallel asynchronous paths, so I can't halt the first split until after the temp SQL table has been filled.

I COULD do a script destination, caching all the rows then, perform my manipulation after every row has been cached, and then make a custom output with the relevant columns, however, there are many more columns (this is a simplified example), and the maintenance in having to deal with that custom output is overwhelming.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Perhaps I haven't had enough tea yet, but you've lost me after the conditional splits. If the CheckValue is C2, then those rows need to replace the S1.Value with S2.DiffValue. If that were the case, then you don't need a conditional split. Rather, just a Derived Column using the Ternary operator to derive the Value. I don't think that's the case but I don't quite get the all of your rows/none of your rows text. Perhaps more data and/or explanation?

Comment: I knew from the beginning it would be hard to explain properly for me. Anyway, I managed a solution. Check answer - and thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an extra column before the split, called HasNeededValue (paraphrasing for simplicity). Then I removed the splits, replaced with a single script transformation.

On process row, I checked for the values I needed to me met (in the example it was CheckValue = C2) and if it fulfilled my conditions, I set the HasNeededValue to 1. Then I added a sort after the script on HasNeededValue (desc), funneled it all into a new script transformation, containing a list of [ID]'s.

On process row I check if HasNeededValue = 1, if it does, copy DiffValue to Value, and insert the ID into the list. If it doesn't = 1, then I check if the list contains the ID, and copy the DiffValue to Value.

This ensures that the one row that might have the value needed to set the value on ALL of the rows is always first, and I know which ID it is, for the rows which doesn't have the necessary conditions.